# Which Debian architecture should I use for my Intel NUC7I3BNH?

Tags: debian, intel, 64bit, x86, architecture

I tried to search for the correct architecture to use for my  [Intel NUC7I3BNH](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc7i3bnh.html), but I am none the wiser.
Which architecture would be most appropriate - amd64 or i386?

Comment: now I get it: an Intel **i3** should of course go with a **i3**86 build. Googling your model gives _Processor Included Intel® Core™ i3-7100U Processor (3M Cache, 2.40 GHz)_, and then you don't have to rely on what it says about windows. Or then, find out about "core i3", and you see: 64-bit since 2010. Thus: AMD. Simple!

Comment: "i386" comes from Intel 80386
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80386

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95066/intel-nuc-kit-nuc7i3bnh.html states, that it supports Windows x64 you should go for amd64.

Comment: Yes Microsoft call the AMD64 / x86-64, x64 because they think 86×2=64.